# jQuery Ajax PUT not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, rest

The following ajax works exactly as advertised in Chrome.  HTTP PUT is used to trigger the insertion of an object into a RESTful API.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: "/ajax/rest/team/create/",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(teamObject),
            success: function (response) {
                teamObject = response.object;
            }
        });
```

I note that the jQuery API docs helpfully tell me that PUT and DELETE may work but are not guaranteed in all browsers.  Such as is my problem.

How is a RESTful API supposed to be implemented on the client side with a problem like this?

EDIT: Firebug tells me that FF is indeed issuing a PUT, but for some currently unknown reason it's dying before getting to the server.  To repeat, this works fine in Chrome.

EDIT: Fiddler doesn't see the FF attempt at all.  :(

Comment: There's a header many backends support (or you may be able to extend the framework to support it): `X-HTTP-Method-Override`. Basically it allows you to make e.g. a `POST` call but make it appear as an `PUT`, `DELETE` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following to work.

```
var payload = JSON.stringify(teamObject)
syncHTTP('/ajax/rest/team/create/', 'PUT', payload);

function syncHTTP(url,method,payload) {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

    client.open(method, url, false);
    client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    client.send(payload);
}
```

I'd rather use jQuery than roll my own tho.  :|  If anyone ever figures it out, just add an answer and if it works I'll accept it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/ajax/rest/team/create/",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        processData: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(teamObject),
        success: function (response) {
            teamObject = response.object;
        }
    });
```

You need to add contentType. When contentType is set to application/json jquery do not try to create JSON object from JSON string but send it as is - as string.

Comment: Can you explain why your changes might help?

Comment: @krun next time post some clarification, instead of just pasting code here

Comment: Hi sorry, that i didn't explain is as well as it should be.